# generic method for collection of command buttons

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

How can we provide single generic method for collection of command buttons. I have collection of digit(0, 1,2..) command buttons and need to have single event method for all of them as they have similar behavior.

Comment: pls show your tried code

Comment: do you mean invoking each button with one single method?? like commandButtons1.Click += new EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by [Multicast Delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173175.aspx)

1. Define `GenericButtonClick` event handler this way:

   ```
   void OnGenenicButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       var btn = sender as Button;
       // ... do something ...
   }
   ```
2. Assign the `GenericButtonClick` event delegate this way (in say `Load` event handler):

   ```
   cmdBtn1.Click += OnGenenicButtonClick;
   cmdBtn2.Click += OnGenenicButtonClick;
   //...
   ```

Reference:

- You can also have a look at the difference of [Simple Delegate (delegate) vs. Multicast delegates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192219/simple-delegate-delegate-vs-multicast-delegates)

Answer (score 2):

The pattern for delegates for events is use two parameters.  One is the sender, the other is the eventargs.  You can do something based on the sender or you can put some stuff in the tag

```
void OnButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button button = sender as Button;

            object data = button.Tag;
            DoSomething(data);
        }
```